# How do Gmail, FB, etc. create web notifications while they're not open?

Tags: gmail, facebook, google-chrome, notifications

I get notifications from Gmail and Facebook while they're not open. I don't have their apps installed either. How are they sending me notifications? I'm guessing they're creating a background service somehow and using that to create notifications using the Web Notifications API.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Have you checked: Settings - Show advanced settings... - System - Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed?

Comment: I currently don't have access to the machine I was using. If the checkbox is checked, what technology are they using to send me the notification?